# Locking multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I have a situtation where in out of multiple instances of a class 2 undergo an operation which leads to the state change of both, since this is a multithreaded application i want to ensure that unless that particular piece of code is executed, none of the other threads which are trying to access any of the aforementioned 2 instances be in waiting state.
Using synchronized or lock we can acquire lock on a single instance and nesting the synchronized block on 2 objects isn't a great idea either.

```
synchronized(obj1){
 synchronized(obj2){
 }
}
```

Another potential problem is that there could be cases where even though the inner object obj2 is free, since the outer object is locked the thread keeps waiting. 
What could be the best possible solution to this problem.

Comment: "Nesting the synchronized block on 2 objects isn't a great idea either." why not? What kind of code paths do you have? You want to avoid a deadlock after all, so even if `obj2` were free, that shouldn't matter if `obj1` isn't.

Comment: it would be a problem if there were another piece of code like `sync(obj2) { sync(obj1) {...} }`

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are they locked independently too? I would suggest using a `Lock` - and always locking that before accessing the objects. Also, with a `Lock` you can `tryLock` and therefore prevent deadlock - in the case where you must acquire the locks sequentially.

Comment: yeah so if there is basically an operation in reverse order of objects it could end up in deadlock

Comment: Yes that would be a problem, so the solution is to ensure that there isn't such a piece of code. Your question?

Answer (score 1):

Having nested locks introduce risk of *deadlock* when two different threads aqcuire locks in different order.

There is no universal approach for eliminate such deadlocks. Possible solutions includes:

1. Maintain **total order** of lock objects, and acquire locks only in ascending order of objects(or only in descending order).

   This is good solution for cases, when both objects for lock are known without needs to lock one of the objects.
2. Using `tryLock` mechanism for inner lock.

   `tryLock` returns false immediately if the object is already locked by the other thread. So a program should process this case somehow.